# java programming exercise debug program

Tags: java

I want to say thank you for reviewing my post and any contributions to my problem i am having. I am fairly new to java so i was wondering if you guys could please help me debug this program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DebugExercise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String area, inStr;
        int pages;

        System.out.println("Please enter your city");
        area = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter page number " + area + "'s phone book");
        pages = input.nextInt();

        PhoneBook phoneBook = new PhoneBook(area, pages);
        phoneBook.display();
    }
}

class PhoneBook extends Book {

    private String area;
    private String size;

    PhoneBook(int pages, String city) {
        super();
        area = city;
        if (pages > 300) {
            size = "big";
        } else {
            size = "small";
        }
    }

    public display() {
        System.out.println( area + pages + size);
    }
}

class Book {

    protected int pages;

    public Book(int pages) {
        pages = pages;
    }

    public int getPages() {
        return pages;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: I spot a couple of the bugs there was one in the main and class brace missing.

Comment: I need to debug the program and cannot find the other bugs within the program. I am not a good debugger.

Comment: I am fairly new to java and not a good programmer

Comment: @johndoe, What, specifically, is wrong with the program? Is it not compiling? Is it compiling, but not giving the answer you want? If you are getting errors, which ones are they?

Comment: The Phonebook constructor (or the call to it) has its parameters reversed? Also, it doesn't pass its pages parameter to its super constructor.

Comment: @StevenJeffries yes exactly it is not giving me the answer i want but it is giving me errors ill post the errors.

Comment: This is the error i am getting: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public display() {

Comment: Ah, you need to specify a return type. Make it "public void display()".

Comment: okay now i have two errors that popped up. There is something wrong with my object in my main method. I get this error for the object: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
        PhoneBook phoneBook = new PhoneBook(area, pages);

Comment: and in the super(); i am getting this error: rror: constructor Book in class Book cannot be applied to given types;

Comment: Give us a sample input and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap the arguments to the phonebook constructor

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String area, inStr;  //there is no need of inStr as you are not using it so remove it if not used
            int pages;

            System.out.println("Please enter your city");
            area = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please enter page number " + area + "'s phone book");
            pages = input.nextInt();

            PhoneBook phoneBook = new PhoneBook(pages,area); //swapp the argurments
              phoneBook.display(pages, area); //add arguments to this otherwise it will just show 0 
        }
```

And in your phonebook class add argument to super

```
    PhoneBook(int pages, String city) {
        super(pages);  // u can even remove this its not needed
        area = city;
        if (pages > 300) {
            size = "big";
        } else {
            size = "small";
        }

public void display(int pages,String area) {
    System.out.println( area + pages + size);
}
}
```

Now it will work

Comment: thank you it worked but it needs to display the city the page number and if it is big or small according to the if statement

Comment: I believe there is another hidden bug that is stopping from displaying the page number to the println statement

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a few elementary problems:

1. in your `Phonebook` class's constructor `PhoneBook(int pages, String city)`, you call `super()`, but there is no empty constructor for class Book, so you must call `super(pages)`.
2. In the constructor of the `Book` class, you are assigning the `pages` variable it's own value. what you probably meant to do is `this.pages = pages;`. By using `this.pages` you tell java that you are referring to the field `pages` of the object that you are creating, and not to the parameter that is passed to the constructor. you can read more about the `this` keyword in Oracle's documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)